# Get short Google Map URL to share in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, url, dictionary, short

I have latitude, longitude of the center of map view and zoom of the view. How can I generate the URL like this https://goo.gl/maps/twqcy in iOS? So that I can send my friend message like this: "Please go to this place: https://goo.gl/maps/twqcy".

I searched for the answer, and here is what I got: I can build a string like:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/@20.982375,105.7903495,17z to send to my friends.

However, there are 2 issues:

1) When user tap/click in the link, I want to show a marker. Currently it only center at the point with certain zoom degree that I put in. How can I generate a link, so that when my friend click on the link, he will see a marker?

2) How to change the form of the url to shortened one i.e from https://www.google.com/maps/place/@20.982375,105.7903495,17z to https://goo.gl/maps/twqcy.

Please answer with code in iOS, preferably in Swift.

UPDATE: This answer my question: [Get url shortened with Google API, AFNetworking in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071395/get-url-shortened-with-google-api-afnetworking-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

returns directly a shortened NSURL
https://github.com/H2CO3/Shortener/blob/master/NSURL+Shortener.m

Comment: Thanks, it seems to answer my 2nd question. But how about 1st question - link with marker added in?